# Error when using 'boolean' type property in spfx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

I have used office ui fabric 'Checkbox' component in my spfx. For storing value of checkbox I have declared one property with name 'var_Passport' as 'boolean' type. further, I'm assigning value (true/false) to that property using 'SetState'. But when I build the project, Below error is logging on the console,

```
[12:18:40] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/ifrsNewContract/components/IfrsNewContract.tsx(50,1): error TS2322: Type '{ var_JobTitle: string; var_JobDescription: string; var_Technology: undefined; var_Salary: undefi...' is not assignable
to type 'Readonly<IVariables>'.
[12:18:40] [tsc] Types of property 'var_Passport' are incompatible.
[12:18:40] [tsc] Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
[12:18:40] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 21 s
 exited with code 2
```

I'm not getting why its saying that 'Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string',  where  I'm not assigning any string value to 'Var_Passport' in my entire code !

For your reference, Below are my code snippets:

**My Interface:**

```
export interface IVariables
{
  var_JobTitle:string | undefined;
  var_JobDescription:string | undefined;
  var_Technology: { key: string | string | undefined };
  var_Salary:string | undefined;
  var_Age:string | undefined;
  var_JoiningDate:Date;
  var_Location:{ key: string | number | undefined };
  var_Passport:boolean;
  var_Manager:IPersonaProps[];
}
```

**My Constructor:**

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state={
var_JobTitle:"",
var_JobDescription:"",
var_Technology:undefined,
var_Salary:undefined,
var_Age:undefined,
var_JoiningDate:undefined,
var_Location:undefined,
var_Passport: false,
var_Manager:[] 
}
```

**My SetState Function:**

```
private _onPassportCheckboxChange = (item: boolean):void => {
this.setState({var_Passport:item},function() {console.log("setState Completed",this.state.var_Passport) });
}
```

**My Checkbox:**

```
<Checkbox label="Do you have passport?" onChange ={this._onPassportCheckboxChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The onChange methods first parameter is of type React.FormEvent and the second parameter is of type boolean.

Go to this link and check out the first example code: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/checkbox

Change your code to this (haven't tested it):

```
private _onPassportCheckboxChange = (item: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement>, isChecked: boolean):void => {
    this.setState({var_Passport:isChecked},function() {
        console.log("setState Completed",this.state.var_Passport);
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried this, Same issue.

Comment: I think its because of specific version of react/typescript which unable to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding undefined to property 'var_Passport' solved my issue.

```
export interface IVariables
{
  var_JobTitle:string | undefined;
  var_JobDescription:string | undefined;
  var_Technology: { key: string | string | undefined };
  var_Salary:string | undefined;
  var_Age:string | undefined;
  var_JoiningDate:Date;
  var_Location:{ key: string | number | undefined };
  var_Passport:boolean | undefined;
  var_Manager:IPersonaProps[];
}
```